# Как в Delphi 10.3 можно сменить скин программы?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Когда-то видел как-то можно, delphi давно не пользовался. Если такого функционала не предусмотрено, посоветуйте лучшее дополнение для Delphi 10.3.

Comment: VCL или Firemonkey?

Comment: Что имеется в виду под "скин программы"? Собственно, скин *самой IDE* или *приложения*, которое Вы напишите с помощью IDE? Из вопроса это не слишком понятно.

Comment: Стили компонентов и окна для программы windows.

Comment: Для Windows программа может быть написана на контролах VCL, и у них один способ стилизации, и на Firemonkey, у которой возможности стилизации другие (например через StyleBook).

Answer (score 1):

Сам разобрался. Project -> Options -> Application -> Appearance -> Custom Styles